# How to use webpack to create a front end and a admin?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am actually new on node.js. I am trying to create an app with admin and frontend using webpack and express. I have created an example app but now the problem is how I can create the app with the admin. Below I have shared my webpack config file

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        frontend: './src/index',
        backend: './admin/index'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style?sourceMap',
                    'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './public',
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Webpack production configuration file

```
var config = require('./webpack.config.js');
var webpack = require('webpack');

config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env": {
      "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
    }
  })
);

config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
      warnings: false
    }
  })
);
```

Is there any easy solution or what I can do now?

Comment: admin is usually a user role feature, which is an application level thing or database thing, and does not have to do with webpack. webpack has nothing to do with that feature.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Thanks, buddy! But I want a multi-entry. So that I can develop a full-featured app with separated admin dashboard and frontend.

Comment: "Buddy" can be interpreted as a demeaning moniker, in general something to avoid. One thing to note is you don't need a multipage app in order to have an admin page, you can a similar thing with just a single page app.

Comment: @AlexanderMills please don't mind. I didn't mean to heart you. actually here is a prob to use authentication way. I cannot use the same UI framework. The styles are getting rude. Its effecting both front-end and admin. like if I use a CSS to modify the header of the frontend its effecting the admin also. Is there any way to use conditional CSS importing in react or web pack. I am actually getting tired to searching more and more.

Comment: Yeah, maybe look into using Angular5 instead of React. Angular5 is setup so that the styles only affect one view